# Is there a chazakah (halachic presumption) that an Eruv is down after a blizzard?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, snow

I remember, I was once at shul Friday night, and it was just starting to snow and it was predicted to be a huge blizzard. The Rabbi got up and announced that tomorrow people should work under the assumption that the Eruv is down, because there is a strong chance that the snow over night will knock it out, and therefore one should not carry unless Bi'shaas Edchak. Another Rabbi from Yeshiva I later spoke to disagreed with the ruling and felt that unless you know the Eruv was down there is no issue. Could anyone gives sources supporting if there should be a Chazakah (halachic/legal presumption) that the Eruv is still up or a Chazakah that it is down in such a conditions?

Comment: Why should there be a general rule about snow? In areas where the boundary is demarcated by things which snow wouldn't affect, then why would snow affect it? If it's in a place where rain affect is (eg. fences made of candy-glass) then even rain ought be a problem. If it utilizes snowdrifts then a sunny day might be problematic, or sand dunes and a tornado.

Comment: The local Rav Hamachshir of my community eruv with decades of experience told me that high winds which knock down branches and eruv lines and freezing rain which can cause the eruv lines to weigh down and snap are problematic. Snow by itself is not a problem

Comment: Well it may become a chazzaka dreiussa,if you know that it was a very heavy snowfall which is known to mess the eruv up

Comment: I was told the same thing Yoni was. The question is a pragmatic one, and in practice unless the blizzard came with freezing rain or downed branches, it is not likely to knock the standard fishing line, wire and highway fencing eruv down.

Comment: Every eruv is different. Whether an eruv has a chazakah of being up or down after a snow storm must be based on the construction and history of each eruv by itself. For example, for last week's east coast blizzard, the Silver Spring, MD (Kemp Mill & White Oak) eruv was up, while the Olney, MD eruv was down because each eruv's Rabbi and administrator knew what factors were most likely to impact their own eruv and decided based on that. I don't know what Olney's consideration was, but what @Yoni said is one of the reasons that Silver Spring was up.

Comment: Check out this article from the National Eruv Initiative: [What causes an Eruv to become physically broken?](http://eruvinitiative.org/multimedia-archive/what-causes-an-eruv-to-become-physically-broken/)